# code to block colour an image placeholders whilst the content loads

Tags: wordpress, loading

I'm struggling to find some code to block colour my image placeholders whilst the content loads. The content on my home page fetches data from the dB and takes about 3 seconds to load dependant on connection speed. Using Wordpress, I'm trying to create somthing similar to the solid pink on http://www.lyricsandtype.com/ and the multi colour on image grid on Theo http://www.theo-theo.com/

any pointers would be greatly appreciated!
thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a simple background color. It is visible when the image isn't loaded yet, then it is just covered. You can create different classes with a `background-color` for each like this:

```
.blue{ background-color: blue;}
.yellow{ background-color: yellow;}
.red{ background-color: red;}
```

Then apply a background-color to a container by calling its class like this:

```
<div class="red">the div content</div>
<div class="yellow">the div content</div>
```

Is it what you were after?